# Davinci Resolve Fusion Media In get two different clips from the timeline in adjustment clip

Tags: davinci-resolve, fusion

I have created a fusion composition in an adjustmen clip that takes two input videos.
My MediaIn1 comes from the "background" and my MediaIn2 comes from the MediaPool.

I want to be able to get my MediaIn 1 & 2 from the timeline directly, to make it easier to adjust/swap out clips later on.

I assumed that the "Layer" drop down that shows up when selecting "Timeline" as a Media Source would allow me to do this, but the dropdown is an empty list

[image: MediaIn1 Layer empty list]

Is it possible to get MediaIn from different tracks on the timeline in an adjustment clip in Fusion? If so, how?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to make this work using an adjustment clip, so I'm using a fusion transition instead.

This way I can get my two clips from the "Layer" property and adjust their in/out on from edit tab